# MovieTexture in Unity3D is never ready to play

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, movie, coroutine

I am using a Unity WWW object to load in a movie file that is in ogg theora format, but I am experiencing some strangeness that I have not been able to figure out how to resolve.

For clarification, I have a folder in my Assets folder called "Movies/" which contains all my locally stored movie files.

A C# code snippet of my application follows, which is inside of a class method run with StartCoroutine:

```
WWW www = new WWW("file://" + Application.dataPath + "/Movies/" + movieName + ".ogg");
yield return www;
m_MovieTexture = www.movie;
if (m_MovieTexture == null)
{
    DbgLog("Movie is NULL!");
    return;
}
if (m_MovieTexture.isPlaying)
{
    // Not sure how this can happen, but just in case....
    m_MovieTexture.Stop();
}
else
{
    if (www.error != null)
    {
        DbgLog("Error: " + www.error);
        return;
    }
    DbgLog("Waiting to load " + www.url);
    while (!m_MovieTexture.isReadyToPlay && !www.isDone)
    {
        yield return www;
    }
    DbgLog("Finished Loading");
    if (www.isDone && !m_MovieTexture.isReadyToPlay)
    {
        DbgLog("Weirdness!  File finished loading before movie was ready to play!");
    }
}
m_MovieTexture.Play();
DbgLog("Playing video (" + m_MovieTexture.duration + " seconds)");
while (m_MovieTexture.isPlaying)
    yield return null;
// be kind... rewind.
m_MovieTexture.Stop();
DbgLog("Finished Playing");
m_MovieTexture = null;
```

When the above code executes, the log statements within reveal that the www.isDone property returns true even while m_MovieTexture.isReadyToPlay returns false.  Orignally, the while loop only waited on m_MovieTexture.isReadyToPlay, but that loop waited interminably, so the extra condition was added, which exposed what was really happening.   The duration of the movie is also always -1, and finally, the above code does not appear to wait for the video to play to play at all, in spite of explicitly calling m_MovieTexture.Play() and then looping while m_MovieTexture.isPlaying is true, m_MovieTexture.isPlaying returns false immediately, and the movie never plays (there is code in the OnGUI method which displays the contents of m_MovieTexture if there is any and the movie is playing, but the problem seems to lie in the above code, not the OnGUI method).

Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong here would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the WWW is already a non blocking co-routine. So you can just have a function that instructs your WWW instance to load the video and assign the movie to your m_MovieTexture. Then in your OnGUI or Update function check for

```
if(m_MovieTexture!=null && !m.isPlaying && m.isReadyToPlay) m_MovieTexture.play();
```

Here's the link to [MovieTexture.onIsReadyToplay](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MovieTexture-isReadyToPlay.html) doc.